# How do I remove the words "new post added at"

Tags: wordpress, facebook, jetpack

Every time I make a new post on my wp site, it gets auto published using Jetpack to Facebook, but each Facebook post title starts with **new post added at mysite** - then my post title. How do I remove/format this to only show my post title and not **new post added at mysite**

Answer (score 0):

Does this help at all?

https://jetpack.com/support/publicize/facebook/

Seems using the module allows you to change who is posting on your facebook timeline, so you could set it to your blog this way.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the reply. i am using publicize as part of jetpack - and its showing the issue i am trying to resolve as above